# Does os.path.samefile follow symbolic links?

Tags: python, filesystems, symlink

Python's [`os.path.samefile`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.path.html#os.path.samefile) function tells whether two paths point to the same file.

If `a` is the path to a symlink that points to `b`, will `os.path.samefile("a", "b")` return `True` or `False`? Is that guaranteed across OSes and filesystems?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16914134/1222951) symlinks have their own inode, so `samefile` *should* return `False`. At least on file systems that *have* inodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already found, [`os.path.samefile`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.path.html#os.path.samefile) uses [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.html#os.stat). stat  follows symbolic links:

> This function normally follows symlinks; to stat a symlink add the argument follow_symlinks=False, or use lstat().
>
> This function can support specifying a file descriptor and not following symlinks.

Back to your question:

> If `a` is the path to a symlink that points to `b`, will `os.path.samefile("a", "b")` return `True` or `False`?

This should return `True` since stat follows symbolic links by default.

If you need a function that returns `False` in this case, you can simply create your own using the code you've already found, and the `follow_symlinks=False` with stat.

> Is that guaranteed across OSes and filesystems?

That's a tough one. Even though many high-level languages try to to hide the details of the underlying system from the user, some operations are almost always system dependent. File IO often falls in this category. In fact, File IO is also file system dependent – if you have two different file systems mounted on the same host, the same code might behave differently on both file systems.

In practice, most file systems behave similarly in most cases – you just need to be aware that edge cases do exist. This is why standards exist. If your system is POSIX-compliant, SUS-compliant, or UNIX-based. It's likely `True` will always be returned.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize that `os.stat` would follow symlinks. The default behavior is what I want :)